# Overlapping elements in multibile sets in python

Tags: python-3.x, set

Lets say I have 6 sets:

```
s1 = {"a", "b", "d"}
s2 = {"a", "b", "c"}
s3 = {"a", "c", "d"}
s4 = {"x", "y"}
s5 = {"x", "z"}
s6 = {"u"}
```

I want to get all the maximum overlapping items and still want to know where which sets they came from. (for example in a dictionary like this)

```
result = {"a": [s1, s2, s3], "x": [s4, s5], "u": [s6]}
```

Is there a fancy way to solve this or do I need to look at every possible combination and count my elements?

I only know about intersect to find common elements, but this obviously wont work, when I try to find elements that are not necessary in all sets. Maybe there is a way to work with Counter, but I couldn't wrap my head around it.

Comment: Why does your expected result not reflect the fact that 'b' appears in s1 & s2, and 'd' appears in s1 & s3, as well as the fact that 'c' appears in s2, 'y' appears in s4, and 'z' appears in s5?

Comment: Because I only need the maximum overlapping item. So because there is "a" in s1, s2 und s3, I don't want to get that there is another overlapping item that only occurse in a subset of them.

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this problem is:

```
def main():
    s1 = frozenset({"a", "b", "d"})
    s2 = frozenset({"a", "b", "c"})
    s3 = frozenset({"a", "c", "d"})
    s4 = frozenset({"x", "y"})
    s5 = frozenset({"x", "z"})
    s6 = frozenset({"u"})

    sets = {s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6}

    print(select_keyqueries(sets))


def select_keyqueries(docs):
    kqs = set(doc for subset in docs for doc in subset)
    # one should probably use OrderedDicts
    ms = dict(sorted({kq: set(s for s in docs if kq in s) for kq in kqs}.items(), key=lambda t: len(t[1]), reverse=True))
    
    return greedy(ms, docs)


def greedy(ms, docs):
    found_docs = set()
    solution = dict()
    for kq, kq_docs in ms.items():
        if not kq_docs.issubset(found_docs):
            solution[kq] = kq_docs
            found_docs.update(kq_docs)
            if found_docs == docs:
                break
    return solution
```

The select_keyqueries will count how often every letter occurs in all sets. The greedy will then select for every possible element the maximum amount of sets, and if it finds an element that occurs in multiple sets, but those sets already have an element that represent more sets in general, it will discard this match.

But please feel free to tell me if there is an easier solution or a better performing one.